# seeking simple noarch rpm spec file

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to make a noarch RPM pkg consisting of bunch of python and .png files. No build/compile. Assume I have all the src files tarred up in utp.tgz and I have copied it to rpmbuild/SOURCES/utp-1.0.tgz

Can you provide me with a simple spec file to package this up?

I have tried several versions of spec file, my current one looks like

```
Name:       utp
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    some summary

Group:      Applications/Engineering
License:    Proprietary
URL:        http://www.example.com
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tgz
BuildArch:  noarch
BuildRoot: %{_builddir}/%{name}-root

%description
A very nice description
```

and when I run

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild" --define "_tmppath $(WORKDIR)/rpmbuild/tmp" -vv -ba utp.spec
```

I get the following

```
medi@medi:~/work> tree rpmbuild/
rpmbuild/
├── BUILD
├── BUILDROOT
├── RPMS
│   └── noarch
├── SOURCES
│   └── utp-1.0.tgz
├── SPECS
│   └── utp.spec
├── SRPMS
│   └── utp-1.0-1.el8.src.rpm
└── tmp
    └── rpm-tmp.uFu2e3

8 directories, 4 files
```

I was expecting utp-*.rpm to be under rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a `%files` section (can be empty), otherwise no package will be produced:

```
%files
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, now I have an rpm under RPMS/noarch , but when I query it, it says "(contains no files)" . According to rpm spec, %files need to specify one or more files (one per line). But I have already provided the utp.tgz under SOURCES/,  does'nt rpmbuild deduce that I want to use utp.tgz . Ok can I just put a line like `tar -zvtf %{Source0}`

Comment: Please ask one single question here. I advise you to read rpm guide first to understand how it works.